# How to convert old bag files to newer messagetypes

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, ros-fuerte, sensor-msgs#image, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have many older bag files(fuerte) from our robot system and we want to use them with indigo. The problem is, that the message versions are not the same and they can't be parsed by newer programs. As an Example here is the error message from rosbag when we tried to display an image topic:

```
Client [/image_view_1419002470714874703] wants topic /usb_cam_side/image_raw/compressed to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage/8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]. Dropping connection.
```

Is there a way to convert the files, so we can use them with the newer ros version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199844/how-to-convert-old-bag-files-to-newer-messagetypes/) by [ptw](https://answers.ros.org/users/21180/ptw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bag files can be migrated to new or arbatrary formats with `rosbag check` and  `rosbag fix`.
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/migration
http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#check

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0